# Problem with checking electronig signatures in PDF with .NET using Aspose and IText

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, aspose

So I have a task to check that PDF files are e-signed without verifying them with signing centers like Crypto Pro. 
I tried libraries like Aspose with this code:

```
pdfFileSignature.BindPdf(input);
IList sigNames = (IList)pdfFileSignature.GetSignNames();
```

and Itext with that code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FileName);
AcroFields acroFields = reader.AcroFields;            
List<string> names = acroFields.GetSignatureNames();
```

And both times I get empty list of signatures. And I know there are signatures in PDF file, as I can click them and see their problems, like this one:

[image: PDF e-sig error]

Is there anything I can do?
Will I ever find true love?
42?

Comment: Please share an example signed PDF to reproduce the issue with. In my experience iText does find filled signature fields, and so I assume Aspose does.

Comment: Im afraid I cannot do that yet, as its an NDA-style inner documents :(

Comment: In that case you should consider hiring a consultant knowledgeable in PDFs who can be asked to sign a NDA. Or you could address the Aspose or iText support if you are a customer of theirs respectively.

Comment: Its a wise advice. All of them are.
Anyway, are there any lower-level ways to check PDF for signatures and get their attributes? I guess its somewhere there in the data?

Comment: Well, start looking what kind of signature it is (acroForm? Xfa? ...). Then check whether it is referenced as it should be according to the appropriate specification.

Comment: Please note that the right place to post such issues in official Aspose.PDF Support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf/10). Please post your inquiry there along with sample PDF document so that the scenario can be tested and addressed accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.